# Juniper MX - vlan-ccc double tagged to untagged

Tags: vlan, mpls, juniper-mx, vpls

On an interface to a customer of ours we configured double tagging. This interface is encapsulated with vlan-ccc because it is used in a l2circuit neighbor configuration.
My question is: how can this double-tagged interface be changed to untagged towards the l2circuit connection?

```
unit 1158 {
    encapsulation vlan-ccc;
    vlan-tags outer 0x8100.1158 inner 0x8100.602;
    family ccc {
        mtu 1520;
    }
}

protocols l2circuit 
    traceoptions {
    file l2circuit.log files 5;
    flag all;
}
neighbor xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx {
    interface xe-0/0/3.1158 {
        virtual-circuit-id 1158;
        mtu 1520;
    }
}
```

This works, but on the other side of the l2circuit I have to configure double tagging, which I really don't want to.
How can I do this in a way so that I don't have to use tagging on the other side?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like:

```
protocols {
    l2circuit {
        neighbor xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx {
            interface xe-0/0/3.1158 {
                virtual-circuit-id 1158;
                mtu 1520;
                ignore-encapsulation-mismatch;
            }
        }
    }
}
...
interfaces {
    xe-0/0/3 {
        flexible-vlan-tagging;
        native-vlan-id 1158;
        unit 1158 {
            vlan-id 1158;
            ...
```